# Regular expressions: How to remove all "R.G(*******)" from a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, expression

There are several strings, and I wanna to remove all "R.G(******)" from these strings. For example:

1、Original string：

```
Push("Command", string.Format(R.G("#{0} this is a string"), accID));
```

Result:

```
Push("Command", string.Format("#{0} this is a string", accID));
```

2、Original string：

```
Select(Case(T["AccDirect"]).WhenThen(1, R.G("input")).Else(R.G("output")).As("Direct"));
```

Result:

```
Select(Case(T["AccDirect"]).WhenThen(1, "input").Else("output").As("Direct"));
```

3、Original string：

```
R.G("this is a \"string\"")
```

Result:

```
"this is a \"string\""
```

4、Original string：

```
R.G("this is a (string)")
```

Result:

```
"this is a (string)"
```

5、Original string：

```
AppendLine(string.Format(R.G("[{0}] Error:"), str) + R.G("Contains one of these symbols: \\ / : ; * ? \" \' < > | & +"));
```

Result:

```
AppendLine(string.Format("[{0}] Error:", str) + "Contains one of these symbols: \\ / : ; * ? \" \' < > | & +");
```

6 、Original string：

```
R.G(@"this is the ""1st"" string.
this is the (2nd) string.")
```

Result:

```
@"this is the ""1st"" string.
this is the (2nd) string."
```

Please Help.

Comment: Will the `R.G(...)` items always only exist on a single line?

Comment: Also, do you need to be able to cope with e.g. `R.G("Hello)World")`?

Comment: Shouldn't [this](http://regex101.com/r/jQ7pP1) work for the *current* examples ?

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job.  A simple stateful parser works much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, capture group 0 is your target, group 1 is your replace.

### [Fiddle](http://fiddle.re/vyq56)

```
R[.]G[(]"(.*?[^\\])"[)]
```

Example acting on your #2 and #4 string and a new edge case `R.G("this is a (\"string\")")`

```
var pattern = @"R[.]G[(]\""(.*?[^\\])\""[)]";
var str = "Select(Case(T[\"AccDirect\"]).WhenThen(1, R.G(\"input\")).Else(R.G(\"output\")).As(\"Direct\"));";
var str2 = "R.G(\"this is a (string)\")";
var str3 =  "R.G(\"this is a (\\\"string\\\")\")";

var res =  Regex.Replace(str,pattern, "\"$1\"");
var res2 = Regex.Replace(str2,pattern, "\"$1\"");
var res3 = Regex.Replace(str3,pattern, "\"$1\"");
```

Comment: you're welcome.  Like most regexes it has weaknesses to edge cases so if there are any counter examples please update the question.

Comment: And what about this one:   R.G("this is a (string)")  -> "this is a (string)"           there are () in this string

Comment: yeah that 4th one you added will be a challenge. maybe we can use some kind of lookahead in the capture group 1 to make sure it's followed by a `[^\\]")`  or similar

Comment: ok, i made the the `.*` lazy and made sure the groups bookends were not an escaped quote-bracket sequence `\")`

Comment: lookahead ? I do not understand... I think you are really good, if the 4th is a challenge to you,  it will be impossible for me to resolve it.   Could you do it for me?

Comment: see the update, i didn't go the lookahead route after all. i was just thinking out loud :D

Comment: Thanks again, It does help me a lot.    I am from China, my english is poor,  I can only use simple sentences to communicate with you.

Comment: what if I want to match a multi-line string. Please see the 6th example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(.*)R\.G\(([^)]*)\)(.*)", "$1$2$3");
```

explanation:

```
(.*)     # capture any characters
R.G\(    # then match 'R.G.'
([^)]*)  # then capture anything that isn't ')'
\)       # match end parenthesis
(.*)     # and capture any characters after
```

The $1$2$3 replaces your entire match with capture group 1, 2, and 3. Which effectively removes everything that isn't part of those matches, namely the "R.G(***)" part.

Note that you will run into problems if your strings contain 'R.G' or a right parenthesis somewhere, but depending on your input data, maybe this will do the trick well enough.

Comment: this will fail on example 2 because you are using `.*` bookends